# Как сделать такой круг на SVG?

Tags: svg

подскажите, возможно ли сделать такой круг на svg? Что бы один край имел border-radius а второй прозрачность наложенную а его цвет был градиентом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сделай 2 дуги, одну с круглым концом, другую с градиентом)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто наложить на него маску

https://jsfiddle.net/gzcamoed/

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-1" x2="0" y2="100%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fff"/>
          <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#000"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x2="0" y2="1"
          gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
          gradientTransform="rotate(135, .5, .5)">
          <stop offset="0.4" stop-color="#acb5cb"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#d692b3"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <mask id="mask">
          <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
          <rect x="40%" y="40%" width="60%" height="60%" fill="url(#linear-gradient-1)"/>
        </mask>
      </defs>
        <path fill="none" stroke="url(#linear-gradient-2)"
          stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="3"
          d="M37,95.7a47.54,47.54,0,1,1,13,1.8"
          mask="url(#mask)"/>
    </svg>
```